# Como hacer para que se muestre un menu solo para usuarios de un grupo en Django?

Tags: html, python, django, django-admin, django-templates

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con django y tengo la siguiente consulta
en el admin de django he creado el grupo "Voluntario", al cual le di permisos para que pueda administrar perros (crear, modificar, eliminar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bien ahora en el template, tengo un boton que envia hacia adonde administro a los perros, pero quiero que ese boton, solo puedan verlo los usuarios que forman parte del staff o si son del grupo "Voluntario" que he creado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de momento solo he conseguido que dicho boton, se le muestre a los usuarios que forman parte del staff, pero no se como hacer para que se le aparesca a los miembros del grupo "Voluntario"

como podria solucionarlo??? muchas gracias

Comment: te sugiero revisar este tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa una variable en tu vista y pásala a tu template:

```
def mi_vista(request):
    # Tu código
    es_voluntario = request.user.groups.filter(name='Voluntario').exists()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {
        # Tus otras variables del contexto
        'es_voluntario': es_voluntario
    })
```

Luego en tu template:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff or es_voluntario %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar la etiqueta {{ perms }}, esto devuelve un valor boleano (true o false), siempre y cuando el usuario tenga el permiso o no.

por ejemplo:
Si tiene el grupo **voluntario**, con permiso **view_perro**, has lo siguiente:

```
{% if perms.core.view_perro %} aquí iría el html de tu menú {% elseif %}
```

Utilizando la etiqueta {{ perms }}, así muestro o no partes de mi template, de acuerdo a la pertenencia a grupos.